# Schema changes in transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, schema, transactional-replication

I have a publisher (SQL Server cluster)  in one box  and the distributor/subscriber together is on the other box. I have a requirement by the vendor that if there is a new build (schema/database changes)  then i will always have to intialise from a back up. I am confused about the steps to do... Below is my plan:

1. Delete/Drop Subscription
2. Disable/Delete  Publication
3. Reconfigure publication with initialise form back up
4. Restore from Full backup on subscriber and apply differential as is in simple mode
5. set up subscription using the last differential file.

Please advice is there any need to delete/disable the distribution database

Comment: See: Deep Dive on Initialize from Backup for Transactional Replication https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2010/03/16/deep-dive-on-initialize-from-backup-for-transactional-replication/

Comment: Thanks for the information,,,,So basically if i set to initialise from back up then I will have to remove publication and subscription and start setting those up again.....Is there anything that needs to be done for the distributor or it can stay as is ...please help !